# SharePoint Webpart Caching Considerations on Load Balanced Server

Tags: caching, sharepoint-2010, load-balancing

Could anyone tell me if its ok to cache my custom made webparts in a load balanced server environment?

Would caching cause any webpart dependencies on one server specifically or will the cache be stored across all servers?

I am caching list entries and user profiles returned from using UserProfileManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching is done in-memory per server, unless you build something to synchronize it across the servers.

Comment: Would this cause any issues if I left my caching on a per server basis?

Comment: As long as you use sticky sessions on your load balancer then your users should not notice...